# Converting ttf to ttc

Tags: macos, fonts, truetype, file-conversion

Is there any way to convert ttf to ttc on windows? I couldn't find one
tried fontforge but didn't work. a few online convertors I tried can't convert to ttc format
Thank you

Comment: What didn't work in Fontforge? Read how to generate TTC: http://fontforge.org/generate.html (second last paragraph).

Comment: What problem are you attempting to solve by converting a single (?) TTF to TTC? TTC is really just TTF under the hood and is designed to solve a very specific problem, that of creating multiple "virtual" fonts from a single file, by sharing data (glyph data, usually). If you have a TTF that doesn't work under Windows, simply converting to TTC probably won't make it work.

Comment: Yes thats the problem actually I want to creat ttc fpnt to use in my jailbroken Iphone..